# How to determine the most common substring

Tags: count

I want to find the repeated sentences/pharses and count their frequence in paragraphs or documents.

ex:
The paragraph:

**On the Insert tab**, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document. You can use these galleries to insert tables, headers, footers, lists, cover pages, and other document building blocks. When you create pictures, charts, or diagrams, they also coordinate with your current document look. You can easily change the formatting of selected text in the document text by choosing a look for the selected text from the Quick Styles gallery on the Home tab. You can also format text directly by using the other controls on the Home tab. Most controls offer a choice of using the look from the current theme or using a format that you specify directly. To change the overall look of your document, choose new Theme elements on the Page Layout tab. To change the looks available in the Quick Style gallery, use the Change Current Quick Style Set command. Both the Themes gallery and the Quick Styles gallery provide reset commands so that you can always restore the look of your document to the original contained in your current template. **On the Insert tab**, the galleries include items that are designed to coordinate with the overall look of your document.

One of the repeated sentences/pharses is *"On the Insert tab"*.
Its frequence is *2*. How to find all of them?

Do you have any idea?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define what you mean by a "phrase". If you can define it as a minimum number of matching words, say 4, then you can go through the document generating all the [4-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngram). Put those in a map from 4-gram to location, and you can quickly find the matches that way.

Comment: I want to find a phrase with maximum number of matching words. This number is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an algorithm design question, as it is achievable by brute force, but there must also be a nice divide and conquer solution.

As @justinvf states, you must first define a minimum length in order to get any meaningful result, otherwise your most repeated phrase is almost certainly going to be `e`, as this is the most commonly occurring character (in English anyway).

The brute force method would be to count all phrases of your minimum length $m$, by using substring `str[0:m]...[0+1:m+1]...` all the way to then end of the paragraph, counting any repeats as you go.  Then increase the increment to 2 and repeat. Seems like the time complexity would be something like $\mathcal{O} (n^{n-m})$ where $n$ is the number of characters in the paragraph.

T̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶i̶v̶i̶d̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶q̶u̶e̶r̶ ̶a̶p̶p̶r̶o̶a̶c̶h̶ ̶w̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶c̶u̶r̶s̶i̶v̶e̶l̶y̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶s̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶e̶p̶s̶:̶ ̶ ̶1̶.̶ ̶C̶a̶l̶c̶u̶l̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶h̶r̶a̶s̶e̶-̶f̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶L̶H̶S̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶2̶.̶ ̶C̶a̶l̶c̶u̶l̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶h̶r̶a̶s̶e̶-̶f̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶R̶H̶S̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶3̶.̶ ̶C̶a̶l̶c̶u̶l̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶h̶r̶a̶s̶e̶-̶f̶r̶e̶q̶u̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶'̶s̶p̶l̶i̶t̶'̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶s̶.̶.̶ ̶i̶.̶e̶.̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶a̶d̶d̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶m̶i̶d̶p̶o̶i̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶n̶g̶.̶ ̶ ̶T̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶o̶f̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶p̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶m̶y̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶m̶a̶y̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶u̶n̶f̶o̶r̶s̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶f̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶i̶n̶c̶i̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶.̶ ̶ ̶T̶B̶H̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶o̶u̶n̶d̶s̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶e̶s̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶l̶g̶o̶r̶i̶t̶h̶m̶ ̶d̶e̶s̶i̶g̶n̶ ̶t̶e̶x̶t̶b̶o̶o̶k̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶a̶b̶l̶y̶ ̶h̶a̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶n̶e̶a̶t̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶l̶r̶e̶a̶d̶y̶.̶

EDIT: However the most optimal solution is to build a [Suffix Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)